# Angular Material 7: Secondary color not applied to Chips

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-components-web

Is it possible to apply secondary color to Angular Material Chips?

My own example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-chip-colors?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) will only display primary and accent colors, not secondary.

[Material example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xnxnpngborg?file=app%2Fchips-overview-example.html) doesn't use secondary

[Angular Material Chips Overview](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)

Answer (score 2):

Accent is meant to be the secondary option for color.
Secondary doesn't exists on his own.

Comment: The terminology used isn't exactly clear. In the deeppurple-amber.css theme, amber is the secondary color, but to use that, we refer to it as "accent" 


"A secondary color provides more ways to accent and distinguish your product. Having a secondary color is optional, and should be applied sparingly to accent select parts of your UI." https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation

So in other words, accent = secondary.